# Create a massive tree from anytree from a text file (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree

I'm working with some massive trees and I want to be able to store them in text files and reconstruct them elsewhere without having to recreate the tree each time.

I'm using AnyTree to make my trees. The trees contain numpy arrays, so JSON conversion is not supported. I'm exporting them as nested dictionaries.

This is how I write the tree to a text file.

```
#Exports the tree to the given filename as a dictionary
def TreetoDict(filename, root):
    exporter = DictExporter()
    dictoutput = exporter.export(root)
    string = str(dictoutput)
    with open(filename,"w") as f:
        f.write(string)
        f.close()
    print("Finished writing")
    return dictoutput
```

Since the tree is so large, I presume turning the dictionary to a string put a lot of line breaks in the form of " " without my consent.

This is what the text file looks like.

```
 ("{'center': array([0, 0, 0]), 'radius': 2, 'name': '([0 0 0],2)', "
 "'numpoints': 0, 'centerofmass': array([0, 0, 0]), 'children': [{'center': "
 "array([1., 1., 1.]), 'radius': 1.0, 'name': '([1. 1. 1.],1.0)', 'numpoints': "
 "0, 'centerofmass': array([0, 0, 0]), 'children': [{'center': array([1.5, "
 "1.5, 1.5]), 'radius': 0.5, 'name': '([1.5 1.5 1.5],0.5)', 'numpoints': 0, "
 "'centerofmass': array([0, 0, 0])}, {'center': array([1.5, 1.5, 0.5]), "
 "'radius': 0.5, 'name': '([1.5 1.5 0.5],0.5)', 'numpoints': 0, "
 "'centerofmass': array([0, 0, 0]), 'children': [{'center': array([1.75, 1.75, "
 "0.75]), 'radius': 0.25, 'name': '([1.75 1.75 0.75],0.25)', 'numpoints': 0, "
 "'centerofmass': array([0, 0, 0]), 'children': [{'center': array([1.875, "
 "1.875, 0.875]), 'radius': 0.125, 'name': '([1.875 1.875 0.875],0.125)', "
 "'numpoints': 0, 'centerofmass': array([0, 0, 0])}, {'center': array([1.875, " etc.
```

How can I can format the dictionary as a string to be put in a text file, which I can subsequently read to reconstruct the tree?

Answer (score 0):

this seems like an appropriate use case for xml

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_tree.asp

there are a number of libs that support:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html